# How to pass props using element in react-router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to reuse my MainSection component for two different purposes (single story and all stories). To effect this, I want to pass in a property, home, in the Routes that go to those renderings of that component. Home is true or false, and I want to render the MainSection component based on that boolean. However, I home keeps being undefined when MainSection gets rendered. The link and route are updating the URL, but not rendering with the props I want. Am I doing something wrong?

Here are my routes:

```
function Routes(){
  return(
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/"  element={<MainSection home={true} />} />
      <Route path="/story" element={ <MainSection home={false} />} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

and here is the code for my MainSection component:

```
function MainSection({ home }){
  console.log(home)
  return(
    <div className="main-section">
      <BigPicture home={ home }/>
      <Quotes home={ home }/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The console log keeps returning undefined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since in the question title you state you are using `react-router-dom` version 6 I'll answer against that. V6 doesn't export a `Switch` component, it was replaced by a `Routes` component. Swap the `Switch` for the `Routes` component and rename your `Routes` component to something else to avoid the name collision.

```
function MainRoutes(){
  return(
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<MainSection home />} />
      <Route path="/story" element={<MainSection />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

From here the `home` prop should either be treated as truthy/falsey. You can double-bang it to coerce it to a strict boolean value. Passing `home` through to children components should also work without issue.

```
function MainSection({ home }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(!!home);
  }, [home]);

  return(
    <div className="main-section">
      <BigPicture home={home} />
      <Quotes home={home} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: how to pass `default` props here?

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh Can you clarify what you are asking to pass as props and where you want to pass them?

Comment: some `default` props like objects have `history` `match` and `location`
In the older version, we do something like this `<Route path="/" render={(props)=><MainSection {...props} home={home}/> }`
but when I try this in latest version I unable to use `arrow` function

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh RRDv6 removed the route props. If you need to access the v6 versions of these objects you will use the React hooks, `useNavigate` for a `navigate` function which replaced the `history` object, `useParams` for `params` instead of `match.params`, and `useLocation` for `location`. I *highly* suggest reviewing the [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5) for the changes from v5 to v6.