# Passing props through route in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to reactjs and have simple question. I want to pass auth props to Login component and want to update its value from within Login component. How can I pass auth to Login component and update its value from Login component.

Secondly, I have one protected route and only logged-in users can open that component. I added Private method to implement this. Is this right approach of making some components protected ?

```
import "./App.css";
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Routes,
    Route,
    Switch,
    Navigate,
    NavLink,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import RequestDemo from "./pages/RequestDemo";
import ProtectedRoute from "./Protected.Route";

const auth = true; //your logic

const Private = ({ Component }) => {
    return auth ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route exact path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route
                    path="/RequestDemo"
                    element={<Private Component={RequestDemo} />}
                />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: There's more than one way for protected route. Yes, you can do it like that as mentioned in code snippet.

Comment: Right, can u please tell how i can pass auth from app.js to Login component and update its value in Login component ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass props using element in react-router v6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70443591/how-to-pass-props-using-element-in-react-router-v6)

Comment: Question is a little too broad and unfocused. Passing props to `Login` works just like it does anywhere else in React... just pass the props you need to pass. As for protecting routes, see this [answer](/a/66289280/8690857) for explanation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

For auth variable I would suggest using as a State or context, below I have provided an example using context, you can do it with State also

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter,Routes, Route, Switch, Navigate, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './pages/Home';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import RequestDemo from './pages/RequestDemo';
import ProtectedRoute from './Protected.Route';
import { useContext } from 'react';

// In the login Component

const LoginComponent = () => {
  const authContext = useContext(MyContext);

  const handleLogin = () => {
    authContext.onAuthChange(true); // this will make the user login that change the value of auth to true
  }

  return (
    <div>Login JSX</div>
  )
}

const MyContext = React.createContext(null);

const Private = ({Component}) => {
  const authContext = useContext(MyContext);
  return authContext.auth ? <Component  /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
}

function App() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(true);

  const handleAuthChange = (newAuthState) => {
    setAuth(newAuthState);
  }

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{
      auth,
      onAuthChange: handleAuthChange
    }}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path='/Login' element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='/RequestDemo' element={<Private Component={RequestDemo} />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </MyContext.Provider>
    
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

**1.** In your case first you have to change `auth` from `const` to `let` as you want to change `auth`. Then you have to pass `auth` and an **function** which can update `auth` in the same file(where `auth` is declared) hence you will pass 2 props `auth` and **function** which updates `auth`.
From your code syntax I'm assuming you are using `v6`.

```
import "./App.css";
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Routes,
    Route,
    Switch,
    Navigate,
    NavLink,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import RequestDemo from "./pages/RequestDemo";
import ProtectedRoute from "./Protected.Route";

let auth = true; // you can mutate let and not constant

const authUpdate = (argument) => {
    // update auth in this function and pass this function to the component
    console.log(auth + 1);
    // if you want some argument or parameter you can do so by declaring argument
    console.log(argument); // only if you want to send some argument or else no need
};

const Private = ({ Component }) => {
    return auth ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route
                    exact
                    path="/Login"
                    element={<Login auth={auth} authUpdate={authUpdate} />} // passed auth and authUpdate as props
                />
                <Route
                    path="/RequestDemo"
                    element={<Private Component={RequestDemo} />}
                />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**2.** There's more than one way for protected route. Yes, you can do it like that as mentioned in code snippet.

#### PS: I suggest you to use state for `auth` if you want to trigger re-rendering and want to update `auth` value at parent and child component level both. If component doesn't re-render's then prop/variable won't be updated

```
import { useState } from "react";

const [auth,setauth]=useState(true)

const authUpdate=()=>{
    // pre-steps
    setauth(auth=>!auth)
    // you should avoid passing setauth directly as a prop
    // down the line in child component you can forget what setauth does and you can set something different  
}
```

If you want to use certain variable/state in all child component you can look into Store or Global State concept. You can use [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) or [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) which does not need to pass props from parent component to child component (prop drilling)

Comment: I am following option 1 which you suggested... How will i access auth in Login component  ? i tried the following way but it is not accessing the auth value which i m setting in app.js 
    
   const Login = (props) => {
 return (
         <div className="main-popup">
   {console.log(props.auth)}
  <div>

  )
}

Comment: I updated the code pass it as such auth={auth}. And I would suggest you to use state based as it will rerender. Pardon I passed it as boolean parameter rather then passing as props.

Comment: Why I got downvoted without any positive criticism?